# Как сделать валидным селект?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

проблема с https://select2.org/placeholders

добавляю пустой option для плейсхолдера(в селект), но верстка сразу же становится невалидной

но в документации он также пустой.. (ссылка выше)

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('select[name="department"]').select2({
      placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
      allowClear: true

    }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
      $('.select2-search input').prop('focus', false);
    });


  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="city__select " data-placeholder="Выберете отделение" name="department">
  <option></option>
  <option>отделение № 1 ул. Старо 11</option>
  <option>отделение № 2 ул. Старо 11</option>
  <option>отделение № 3 ул. Старо 11</option>
  <option>отделение № 4 ул. Старо 11</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В каком смысле валидный селект ?